# Load String into RichTextBox

Tags: excel, powershell, richtextbox, vba

I fail at finding a way to Load a String that is NOT coming from a File into a new Instance of an RichTextBox. Specifically, the Text is coming from an Excel-Sheet, that contains RTF-formatted Text.

There is the LoadFile-Method for loading Files into a RichTextBox, that is overloaded for use with Streams:

```
LoadFile(Stream, RichTextBoxStreamType)
```

My Progress so far:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
$rtb = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$rtb.LoadFile($Worksheet.Cells.Item(1,9).Text, [System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBoxStreamType]::RichText)
```

Is this the right way to do it? Am I heading in the wrong direction?

Any Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you just add it as property to the object, like this? `$rtb = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox -property @{ rtf = 
$Worksheet.Cells.Item(1,9).Text }`

Comment: @BenH Thank you that worked! Make it an Answer and I will accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RichTextBox` [class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx) has a property [Rtf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.rtf(v=vs.110).aspx). When constructing a new instance of the RichTextBox, you could set the Rtf property by using the `-property` parameter of `New-Object`:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
$rtb = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox -property @{
    rtf = $Worksheet.Cells.Item(1,9).Text 
}
```